# Not able to format milliseconds with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: apache-flex

I am not able to get milliseconds with DateTimeFormatter. I lost a few hair to this already:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:DateTimeFormatter id="dtf" 
                         dateTimePattern="{pattern.text}"
                         errorText="Invalid input value"/>      
</fx:Declarations>
<s:HGroup>
    <s:TextInput id="pattern" />
    <s:Label text="{dtf.format( new Date())}" />
</s:HGroup>
```

When I type "y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS#" in {pattern} , I am not seeing anything between the dot and the pound sign. Does SSS only work for parsing?

Comment: What happens if you leave off the #?

Comment: You might need to extend DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Your formatString is not correct, however I do not believe that there is support for milliseconds anyway in the default DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: According the the documentation SSS is correct http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html#setDateTimePattern()

Comment: You are refering to the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter` in `flash.globalization` , which is not the same as the `Spark DateTimeFormatter` that is in your code example.

Comment: Although in that same documentation under format() it only states the use of `date, day, fullYear, hours, minutes, month, and seconds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's my solutions then:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:DateTimeFormatter id="dtf" 
                         dateTimePattern="{pattern.text}"
                         errorText="Invalid input value"/>      
</fx:Declarations>
<s:HGroup includeIn="start" bottom="5" left="5">
    <s:TextInput id="pattern" />
    <s:Label text="{dtf.format( new Date()) + (new Date().milliseconds + 1000).toString().substr(1)}" />
</s:HGroup>
```

And the pattern would be  "y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss."

Comment: +1 I guess we need to do it manually, since DateTimeFormatter does not work as documented -_-

Answer (score 1):

Try using the mx DateFormatter formatter rather than spark DateTimeFormatter.

The format strings for date formatting in DateFormatter may are slightly different than other time/date formatters but milliseconds (Q) is supported and does work.

With Apache Flex 4.10 (and above) this code:

```
protected function traceDate():void
{
    var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter()
    df.formatString="YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.QQQQ#";
    trace(df.format(new Date()));
}
```

Produces a time date string like so:
2013-11-30 09:40:11.0528#

Answer (score 0):

End the date string with "." or ":"
example if the date string is "2018-04-19 16:46:49.766"
then make it "2018-04-19 16:46:49.766" + "."
or 
"2018-04-19 16:46:49.766" + ":"